# to html from c# method

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

good afternoon, I want to call from html a method that is in c #

```
<div>
    <div id="divLista row-fluid">
                
            <table id="tblLista" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        
                        <th>Nº</th>
                        <th>Fecha</th>
                        <th>Doc</th>                          
                        <th>Imprimir</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <%
                        if (xItems != null)
                            foreach (var item in xItems)
                            {
                                Response.Write("<tr class='data-row'>");                                   
                                Response.Write("<td>" + item.Id + "</td>");
                                Response.Write("<td>" + item.Fecha.ToShortDateString() + "</td>");
                                Response.Write("<td>" + item.Nro + "</td>");                                  
                                **Response.Write("<td><asp:Button id='btnEdit' class='btn btn-round btn-info btn-xs' runat='server' onserver='btnEdit_ServerClick(" + item +  ")') >Imprimir</asp:Button></td>");**
                                Response.Write("</tr>");
                            }
                    %>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

C#

```
protected void btnEdit_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MostrarError("afasdfsdf");
}
```

Comment: OK.  And your question is?

Comment: sorry I can't access the btnEdit_ServerClick method, thanks

Comment: I think you need `onserverclick` insted of `onserver`.

Comment: I made the change but it does nothing

Comment: You should use aspx form and add server controls there. Response.Write will not add control to the page's control collection.

Comment: You can follow [this tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/adding-web-forms-controls-dynamically-in-Asp-Net-C-Sharp-web-appl/) to add dynamic controls.